# Possible to list all user with specific format using batch script only?

Tags: batch-file

Assume that Powershell is not allowed. Only batch script is allowed.

I use `net user` to obtain the following output:

```
User accounts for \\PC-Demo   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc123                   Administrator            ASPNET
blah_blah                Demo                     Guest
SUPPORT_388945a0         Test
The command completed successfully.
```

and I would like to output a file become

```
abc123
Administrator
ASPNET
blah_blah
Demo
Guest
SUPPORT_388945a0
Test
```

The main problem is it is hard to get the username from the output since this is not separate by delimiter. It is separate by tabular format, also the length is variable, more line will be displayed when there are more user accounts. Or except using `net user`, is there any better way to get user account in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it languag independend but it would require much more than a one-liner.

First you need to count the lines in the output then process the output of the lines with expected content

```
@echo off

set /a linecount=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('net user') do call :IncrementLinecount
set /a lastline=%linecount%

set /a linecount=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('net user') do (
    call :IncrementLinecount
    call :ProcessOutput %%i
)
goto :eof

:IncrementLinecount
set /a linecount=%linecount%+1
goto :eof

:ProcessOutput
if /i %linecount% LEQ 2 goto :eof
if /i %linecount% GEQ %lastline% goto :eof
:loop
if not [%1] == [] (
        shift
        @echo %1
        goto :loop
    )
goto :eof
```

Comment: both `call IncrementLinecount` could be safely replaced by `set /a linecount +=1`; then the `:IncrementLinecount`sub (3 lines)  is not needed anymore. The whole `:loop` (6 lines) could be replaced by `for %%i in (%*) do echo %%i`. +1 for the logic and for being language independent.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I wasn't aware there is a += operator as well as the %* argument to the for loop. Amazing! I'll remember that

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it very much, because it depends on your language (german for me), but here we go:

```
(for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('net user^|findstr /v /b /c:"Benutzerkonten" /c:"----" /c:"Der Befehl" ') do for %%a in (%%b) do echo %%a)>file.txt
```

You will have to change the strings `Benutzerkonten` and `Der Befehl` to your language.

for reference: `net user` output:

```
Benutzerkonten für \\AKOYAD

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            Myuser                Gast
Backup
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
```

Maybe `wmic useraccount get name` is an alternative.